# Green block for days with accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, css

My reputation page displays the following in Chrome and FireFox (both for Mac):

[image: reputation]

It appears there's a little css issue for days that have accepted answers where both the score and the background are the same color (or I'm colorblind and didn't know it).

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Google Chrome for Mac OS X. If this makes any difference, the version of Chrome I am using is 12.0.742.100.

Comment: If it helps, I'm having this issue too.  Firefox 3.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/users/8360/kit?tab=reputation

Comment: This is happening over apple.SE too. [It's being fixed there](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/558/whats-up-with-the-red-on-green-bubbles). Might wanna get in touch with the crew fixing it over there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed now, on all the sites.